# Redirect domain to subdomain but keep the url of the main domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have a website **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**. Recently I created a subdomain **new.example.com** as I was rebuilding the existing website, once I am done, I would want to redirect the main domain to subdomain, but keep the url of the main domain.

So when visitors visit [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) - they see the content of the new.example.com, but the browser's address bar should display main domain`s url => [www.exmaple.com](http://www.exmaple.com). Can you kindly suggest a proper way to accomplish this through .htaccess?

Many thanks!

Comment: That means that the "old" website cannot be accessed anymore. Therefore you can simply change the hosts `DOCUMENT_ROOT` to the location currently holding the content of "new. example.com". As easy as that. No dynamic configuration or request rewriting required.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response - can you kindly advice where I can do it? I could not find it in htaccess file.

Comment: You can't use that setting in a _distributed configuration file_ (".htaccess"). The `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is one of the basic settings in the http server's host configuration. You cannot change it in a dynamic manner. Instead you need to configure that in the central host configuration of the http server.